# How to help Convolutional Neural Network differentate 2 mostly smooth textures?

Tags: conv-neural-network, resnet, medical-imaging

I am trying to build a Convolutional Neural network (at moment using RestNet architecture) to classify mammogram images by density (the classes go from A, very smoothly low density to D, very homogeneous dense ).

It works well   on the middle ranges, but I am facing a problem with extremely  dense and extreme low density  (A and D). The problem is, some very very dense mammograms  are breasts  whose image is completely filled by the dense material, therefore they present a low internal contrast (i.e no edges)...  while the  very low density mammograms  present also a very low internal contrast ( complete lack of such material). For a human is very easy to differentiate them, as  one image is very white while the other is very  dark, but convolutional neural networks care for edges only so they are easily confused.

I wanted to know if there are some techniques that I could use to try to improve the CNN performance to differentiate such cases (2 textures  mostly smooth but with very different base values).

I tried to just use a non AI  decision making  after the CNN made its analysis and measure the average density of the mammogram, but  it felt very crude and I hoped to find something directly usable with the CNN.

Comment: CNNs should be good in doing what you need. Probably the problem is in the preprocessing. Did you use some form of normalization that makes uniform images collapse to the same value?